# Change Colume Name in dataframe and melt it

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I am have a code to merge few excel together using Python, but i cant realy rename any thing in that dataframe using df.rename(). could someone explain why? Thanks!

```
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd


def file_name(file_dir):
    list=[]
    for file in os.listdir(file_dir):
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.xlsx':
            list.append(file)
    return list

path = r'E:\Sync\External\Test'
wks = file_name(path)
data = []   
for i in range(len(wks)):
    read_xlsx = xlrd.open_workbook(path + '\\' + wks[i])
    sheet1 = read_xlsx.sheets()[1] 
    nrow =  sheet1.nrows
    title = sheet1.row_values(0)   
    location = os.path.splitext(wks[i])[0]

    for j in range(6,nrow): 

        a = sheet1.row_values(j)
        a.insert(0,location)
        print(a)
        data.append(a)

content= pd.DataFrame(data)

content.rename({'0': 'X', '1': 'Y'}, axis=1, inplace=True)


#content.to_csv(path+'\\test.xlsx', sep=',', header=True, index=False)

content.to_excel(path+'\\test.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
```

Code as above, no error shows,but it's just doesn't work (rename part)

Comment: You are not specifying in the code that you want to rename column
`content.rename({'0': 'X', '1': 'Y'}, axis=1, inplace=True)`
has to be 
`content.rename(columns={'0': 'X', '1': 'Y'}, axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: I suspect you column names originally are integers and not strings.  Try {0:'X', 1:'Y'} instead of {'0':'X', '1':'Y'}.

Comment: Scott is right.  The default column names when created with a list instead of dict are in integers 0, 1, 2, etc.  rather than string '0', '1', '2', etc.